# Best way to migrate all data from SBS2003 to Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: windows-sbs-2003

Have a Windows SBS2003 server and want to get out from under the SBS setup. Any best scenarios for moving to Windows Server 2008R2? I know I will lose the domain and exchange features any other things I will lose?

Answer (score 0):

SBS isn't in any way a watered down version of Windows or Exchange.

You'll lose Sharepoint, RWW, a nice management console that simplifies adding computers and users to the domain and managing the various SBS components, a fairly decent automated backup solution, integrated fax services, integrated monitoring and reporting, etc., etc.

Comment: Forgive. The watered down statement. However I just want to upgrade to windows server 2008r2. Any recommendations?

Comment: Is your intention to migrate the users as well as the data? What about the email?

Comment: Joeqwerty is asking some great questions, with SBS you get a number of services that aren't bundled with Server 2008 - Exchange, Sharepoint, SQL, etc...which of these are you planning on migrating?

Comment: Mostly users and data. The exchange piece is not an issue. Also the SQL I will install SQL2008r2 server.

Comment: I wonder why you would do this at all if your environment didn't absolutely need it?